# MS Access VBA acImport sheet name with spaces and range

Tags: vba, ms-access, import, ms-access-2010, spreadsheet

I'm building a form with a button called "Go" to import a specific range of a specific excel sheet from an excel file. Another sub/function takes care of having the file name on the form in the field called text_filepathdata.

I've discovered that spaces in the sheet names are problematic, however it can be resolved by using special quotation.

```
Dim sheetname As String
sheetname = "'Commit Volumes!'"
DoCmd.Transferspreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
    "lcl_ImportedFile", text_filepathdata, True, sheetname
```

That works, but I can't specify a range in addition to the sheet name because of the special quotation... (ie. "'Commit Volumes!A6:Z5000'" doesn't work and neither does a concatenation of the two pieces like "'Commit Volumes'" & "A6:Z5000")

I've tried all manner of quotations and concatenations, but the only things that work are:

```
sheetname = "'Commit Volumes!'"
sheetname = "'Commit Volumes$'"
sheetname = "CommitVolumes!A6:Z5000"
```

The excel sheet cannot be modified because it comes from another system and the file (after being updated) must be uploaded back to that system.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub button_Go_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_button_Go_Click

Dim sheetname As String
sheetname = "'Commit Volumes!'"

If IsNull(text_filepathdata) Or text_filepathdata = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please browse and select a valid file to import.", _
        vbCritical, "Invalid File"
Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm "f_PleaseWait_Processing", acNormal, , , acFormReadOnly, acWindowNormal
    If ifTableExists("lcl_ImportedFile") = True Then
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "lcl_ImportedFile"
    End If
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12,_
        "lcl_ImportedFile", text_filepathdata, True, sheetname

'Call module to process the imported data
        Call MainProcess
    End If

Exit_button_Go_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_button_Go_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_button_Go_Click

End Sub
```

I get two different error messages depending on the issue.

If there's a space in the name I get: Run-time error 3129: Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

If there's a problem with the name otherwise I get: Run-time error 3011: The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object "Commit Volumes$A1:Z5000". Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path correctly. If "Commit Volumes$A1:Z5000" is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Bill

Variations I've Tried:

```
sheetname = "'Commit Volumes'!A6:Z5000"; 
sheetname = "'Commit Volumes!'A6:Z5000" 
sheetname = "'Commit Volumes$'A6:Z5000" 
sheetname = "'Commit Volumes'$A6:Z5000" 
sheetname = "'Commit Volumes'$A$6:$Z$5000" 
sheetname = "'Commit Volumes!'$A$6:$Z$5000" 
sheetname = "'Commit Volumes$'$A$6:$Z$5000"
```

Comment: The one variation you didn't try was `Commit Volumes$A6:Z5000` which is in the answer posted by @Scott MacFarlane.  When the sheet name contains a space don't wrap it in single quotes and replace the `!` with `$`.

Answer (score 2):

If the file gets exported from the other system in a known\set format, you could refer to it by index rather than by name:

For Example: sheets(1), sheets(2). Then add the range.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problems.  When I created a range string variable and passed it to the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet routine, Access changed the "!" character to "$" and gave me an error. If I passed a string constant to the Range parameter of the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet routine, Access did not change the character.  In other words, running the following code, ...

```
Dim strFilename As String
Dim strRange As String
Dim strTableName As String

strFilename = "YourWorkbookName.xlsx"
strRange = "Sheet5!A1:Z99"
strTableName = "tblImport"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
  TransferType:=acImport, _
  SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
  TableName:=strTableName, _
  FileName:=strFilename, _
  HasFieldNames:=True, _
  Range:=strRange
```

... gave me the 3011 runtime error.

However, when I separated the sheet name and the address into two separate variables and passed them to the routine, Access was happy.  In other words, when I ran the code, ...

```
Dim strAddress As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim strSheetName As String
Dim strTableName As String

strAddress = "A1:Z99"
strFilename = "YourWorkbookName.xlsx"
strSheetName = "Sheet5"
strTableName = "tblImport"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
  TransferType:=acImport, _
  SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
  TableName:=strTableName, _
  FileName:=strFilename, _
  HasFieldNames:=True, _
  Range:=strSheetName & "!" & strAddress
```

... I received no error and the data from the Sheet5 sheet was properly imported into tblImport.

It should be noted that Sheet5 is not the first sheet of the workbook and strAddress does not have "$" characters in it.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution that works in the two cases I needed it to.

The original poster above and all of the attempts to answer here have not been able to stumble upon the specific format required to get this to work.  I did, through stubborn trial and error, and it is not what any of us expected.

In order to get the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet function to take a specific range on a specific sheet, the "range" parameter must be in the following format:

```
"SheetName$A1:Z100"
```

If SheetName has a space in it, it must be:

```
"Sheet Name$A1:Z100"
```

1. The sheetname must *NOT* be put in single quotes, or the method will
   fail.
2. The sheetname must *NOT* be ended with an exclamation mark
   before the range, or the method will fail.
3. The range (A1:Z100) must *NOT* be in fixed addressing notation, or
   the method will fail.

To summarize:
If you have a workbook named "WB" with two sheets: "S1" and "S 2", and you want to import range A1:Z100 from each of them:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet ,,"TABLE NAME 1","WB",,"S1$A1:Z100"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet ,,"TABLE NAME 2","WB",,"S 2$A1:Z100"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

`'Commit Volumes'!A6:Z5000`

When there is a sheet name with spaces or dashes, excel places single quotes around the sheet name itself, not around the whole reference.

So:

```
sheetname = "'Commit Volumes'!A6:Z5000"
```

Comment: Hi Scott! I tried the code you suggested... I'm still getting the same error message. The error message is not returning what I typed in the code though... message says: The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object "Commit Volumes'$A6:AQ5000'. Make sure...etc. Instead of saying the object is "'Commit Volumes'!A6:AQ5000" like I have in the code. Strange, eh? It must be interpreting what I put in the code differently? Or something else?

Comment: A fellow programmer just advised trying multiple variables like so:
`Dim sheetname as String
Dim cellrange as String
Dim sheetrange as String
sheetname = "'Commit Volumes!'"
cellrange = "A6:Z5000"
sheetrange = sheetname & cellrange`
It seemed promising, but did not, however, work. :(

And forgive me but I can't get the code to appear on multiple lines.

Comment: a shot in the dark, but what if you try brackets `[]` around the sheet name instead of `'`

Comment: Do not use exclamation marks (!), single quotes (') or fixed addressing notation ($A$1).  The format that works would look like this for your example:  "Commit Volumes$A6:Z5000"

Answer (score 0):

use sheetname = "Commit Volumes$" with no range which seems to work by matching the table field names with the excel column headings

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

finally i found that you can use:

sheetname = "Commit Volumes!A6:Z5000"
example
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "table name", _
filetoimport, False, "Commit Volumes!A6:Z5000"

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above proposed solutions and unfortunately it did not work in my case: indeed the import method of Access does not like it when the worksheets have spaces in their names.

I did a workaround: renaming the worksheets during the code to something short and without spaces, for instance: from "Data Q1 2016"  to "WS1". In this way, you can pass the value "WS1$" to the Range argument of the import function, and Access will import the used range of the given worksheet

When importing the second worksheet, I again used the code and renamed it to "WS2"... and so forth.

in summary:  rename the worksheets during code runtime to short names without spaces, and add the '$' symbol at the end to make it grab the used range.